# Влияет ли подмена данных на индексацию?

Tags: seo

Имеем подобный скрипт из просторов Интернета.

```
<script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.onload = function () {
    if(ymaps.geolocation.region == 'Москва и Московская область'){
       jQuery(".region-phone").text('+7 (495) 000-00-00');
       jQuery(".region-phone-href").attr('href', 'tel:+78000000000');
     } else {
       jQuery(".region-phone").text('+7 (800) 000-00-00');
       jQuery(".region-phone-href").attr('href', 'tel:+78000000000');
   }
}
</script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a class="region-phone-href" href="#"><div class="region-phone"></div></a>
```

Если подменять  контактные данные в картечке организации такого вида:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <span itemprop="name">Яндекс</span>
  Контакты:
  <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    Адрес:
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">Льва Толстого, 16</span>
    <span itemprop="postalCode"> 119021</span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Москва</span>,
  </div>
  Телефон:<span itemprop="telephone">+7 495 739–70–00</span>,
  Факс:<span itemprop="faxNumber">+7 495 739–70–70</span>,
  Электронная почта: <span itemprop="email">pr@yandex-team.ru</span>
</div>
```

Повлияет ли это на индексацию данных? И вызовет ли проблемы? Будет ли поисковик видеть все телефоны из скрипта?

Answer (score 0):

- Вы спрашиваете "Если подменять контактные данные в карточке
  организации такого вида: *Повлияет ли это на индексацию данных?*"- нет не повлияет - вы можете устанавливать любые данные, которые необходимы вам.
- Вы спрашиваете "Если подменять контактные данные в карточке организации такого вида: *Будет ли поисковик видеть все телефоны из скрипта?*" - будет видеть, но я предложил бы вам следующую, разметку для телефонов (возможность звонить прямо с сайта) `<a href=tel:+код-страны+номер itemprop=url><span itemprop=telephone>zzzzz</span></a>`

Для проверки вашей разметки используйте **[этот валидатор Гугл](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)**.

Comment: Спасибо, про валидатор и работу со ссылками я в курсе. Мне важно было знать, воспроизводят ли скрипты при считывании данных.